# Jetpack Compose TextField in ModalBottomSheetLayout, keyboard won't hide automatically

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet, android-modalbottomsheetlayout

If hide the bottom sheet by drag gesture then keyboard won't hide automatically

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: If does not close the keyboard. You have to do it manually using ```FocusManager```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shared any code here, this is how I would have handle this issue:

**Use the Disposable Effect and onDispose handle the keyboard hiding**

Sample Code:

```
...
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

  DisposableEffect(key1 = modalBottomSheetState.isVisible, effect = {
        onDispose {
            keyboardController?.hide()
        }
    })
...
```

The LocalSoftwareKeyboardController is marked as Experimental so you can also do the following:

```
...
 val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

  DisposableEffect(key1 = modalBottomSheetState.isVisible, effect = {
        onDispose {
             focusManager.clearFocus()
        }
    })
...
```

Comment: yes, I didn't share it because I didn't add any logic like this. So I didn't think it would make any sense to show how I call this dialog (because it's the same for everyone in Compose with `modalBottomSheetState`), but thanks I will try your method :)

Comment: it works though it has some delay even when bottom sheet totally has been hidden  :)